# Named Pipes on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, named-pipes

I am using named pipes on windows (C++). I was able to send data from one unrelated process to another process.
But for this I have to start the server first. and use "CreateNamedPipe" before I run the client. Client connects to the server using "CreateFile".

Is there a way I could run the client first before starting the server? (without trying to use the "CreateFile" inside a loop till it succeed)

Thank you.

Comment: No. Of course not. There is no named pipe until you have created it.

Comment: You don't have to use a loop though.  Just create a named event as well, and have the server signal the event once the pipe is ready.

Comment: Late to the party, but there is a function exactly for that purpose: WaitNamedPipe

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it depends on your use case. My answer will be based on a case your software doesn't require the named pipe to work. For example, let's say a software which use a named pipe to log activities. This way we can understand your software can work perfectly without logging.

It should be possible if you start up your program without requiring the named pip to exist. Then, once everything is loaded up and functional, you could have sub-routine periodically checking for the named pipe existence (let's say every 5 seconds in order to not overload your CPU) and once created, you start using it.

**Note:** it will still looks like an infinite "a loop till it succeed" but I don't see anything wrong with that since you do it properly, says, you run it with non-blocking mechanism.

**Note:** it doesn't necessarily implies multi-process techniques. You can imagine a single main loop with a periodic checking (not every iteration).